# How to add user in AWeber?

Tags: aweber

I am using AWeber for the first time. I have a live application. I just want to add my user details in AWeber to send them emails. I have a AWeber user account at https://www.aweber.com/ and also have a developer account at https://labs.aweber.com/.

At developers account I have created an app and in the place of "app website" I put my application website. I got "App ID", "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret".

At user account I can create list add subscribers manually and also can send them broadcast emails.

My question is, is there any api to add subscriber in AWeber list that I've created? Or if I have to use the developer account how I can add user in the app without using signup form given by AWeber? Also can I send emails manually to the users added in developer account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Aweber's API does allow you to add subscribers to the lists in your user account. This tutorial will show you how to add a subscriber: http://engineering.aweber.com/quick-start-api-script-in-php/

You can send emails to those users manually from your user account and also via the API. Aweber recently has added features to create and send emails via the API: https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#broadcast_collection